# Phrase for words like "heart rate", "blood pressure", "sweat", etc

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a phrase for words like "heart rate", "blood pressure", "sweat", "temperature", etc.?

Usage example:

> Estimating someone's mood by their [phrase]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my medical training these are called physiological signs and symptoms.

Signs are body responses which can be detected by a medically trained person e.g. Blood pressure

Symptoms are such responses which can be detected by anyone e.g. Sweating, flushing.

Comment: Don't people usually call them "vital signs" or "vitals" for short? In my time as an EMT that's pretty much the only thing they were called

Comment: Sweat isn't a vital sign

Comment: "sweat" isn't measurable. It seems to have snuck in there with some other, measurable things.

Answer (score 24):

A person’s vitals (vital signs).

**[vital signs](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22vital%20signs%22)**
*noun*
clinical measurements, specifically pulse rate, temperature, respiration rate, and blood pressure, that indicate the state of a patient's essential body functions

Comment: Although it's short, this is the best answer. When you're in the hospital, nursing staff come into the room and "check your vitals" on a regular schedule. When you arrive in the ER, one of the first things they do is take vitals. This term is widely used and widely recognized.

Comment: But no one's going to determine your mood by taking you down to ER and accurately measuring your vital signs.

Comment: No one's going to call an ambulance to determine whether you're angry or not